# Who creates the instance of the object that receives as a parameter in Spring

Tags: java, spring

In pure Java we learn that to use the features of a class we must create an object from it through the instance. In Spring, specifically in a post method, when we pass it as a parameter a class and a reference to this class, where is it and who is responsible for instantiating the object that we pass there as a parameter so that the user can register such functionality?

Example:

```
@PostMapping
public User insert(@RequestyBody User user) {
    User result = repository.save(user);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: ...Spring (Boot) does. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/introduction.html

Comment: Do you mean, what instantiates User user?

Comment: Obviously, spring does. More specifically, the [HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) does.

Comment: Yes, because this instantiation is not explicit, my question is who creates an instance of the object that I receive as a parameter in Spring, in this case where and who is responsible for instantiating the "User" Tomas

Answer (score 0):

Outside your actual controller method, there is a flow including JSON parsing, filters, interceptors, argument resolvers etc.
Try this as a good starting point:
https://dzone.com/articles/lifecycle-of-a-request-response-process-for-a-spri

If you are interested the flow, you can print the stack trace
`Thread.dumpStack();` in your controller method and analyze yourself. OFC, the call is debug only, do not use it in real code (just like System.out and System.err)